# Disk usage when redshift doing vacuum merge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I know redshift split vacuum progress into two stages: sort and merge.

During sorting, the disk usage will not change, but merge stage seems will occupy a lot of free space.

My cluster is 3 nodes of dw2.xlarge, total 480 GB SSD. Before vacuuming, the total disk usage is around 50%.

I'm doing a vacuum on a a table of 81GB, but it failed when trying to do merge, due to disk full error.

I want to know how much space should I reserve for vacuuming a large unsorted table?

I asked this question to redshift support team, but haven't got any reply until now. Does anyone have experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes for longer vacuum use [deep copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-deep-copy.html)

This will should avoid disk usage problems.

while you to insert into ( select * from...) here in select you select sorted order for data so that you data will be inserted in sorted fashion.

Do incremental insert into (select * from ) as per your sort key
e.g if you are storing data for 30 days then do deep copy day by day
This should avoid space issues

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  because my old table is totally unsorted, I'm wondering whether deep copy will also take disk space when sorting?

Comment: This is what deep copy says:: " If a table has a large unsorted region, a deep copy is much faster than a vacuum" . one suggestion is while you to insert into ( select * from...) here in select you select sorted order for data so that you data will be inserted in sorted fashion.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a try later, and report the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, deep copy, comes to the same disk usage problem, before deep copy, my disk usage is only 33%, this table occupy about 15% in total. but it consumes the whole left free space. Maybe, I should do   multi deep copy with small data set.

Comment: add increment insert into ( select *) as per your sort key. e.g if you are storing data for 30 days then do deep copy day by day.